# Disable nginx cache for a specific URL in site

Tags: nginx, cache

We want to disable cache on a specific URL in our site.

The problem we have is that when a user buys something, this purchase only is reflected in user's profile when nginx cache is cleared

User's profile URL looks like this:
https://example.com/api/user/content/49642

Comment: Are you using nginx as a reverse proxy? if so, you can control nginx cache using the `Cache-Control` header on the origin server

Comment: Do not post the same question repeatedly. Instead you should edit your original question to improve it.